# How to use msqli multi_query fuction inside a transaction

Tags: php, mysql

I will be running every midnight a cron job (php script) to copy all the records from one table to another and then delete them from the first one table.

Here is what I have for now:

```
<?php

include('conf/conn.php');

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW TABLES FROM mydb LIKE '%salon%'");

while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $tableToCopy = $table[0];

    mysqli_begin_transaction($conn, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);

    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO history SELECT * FROM $tableToCopy");

    // Here is where I'm stuck

    // $sql = "INSERT INTO history SELECT * FROM $tableToCopy; ";
    // $sql.= "DELETE FROM $tableToCopy; ";

    // if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
    //     echo "Both executions failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    // }

    mysqli_commit($conn);

    mysqli_close($conn);

    if (!mysqli_commit($conn)) {
        echo 'Failed.';
        echo '<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'Successful';
        echo '<br>';
    }

}

?>
```

I can't find how to make more than one query inside a transaction. Can someone please guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `multi_query`. Just run each query independently, and then commit afterwards. The queries may run against the database separately, but to each reader, that's reading that table, the queries will happen in one block. (ie. There will never be a time where history will contain items from `$tableToCopy` AND `$tableToCopy` will contain ANY items)

Comment: Mmmm that make sense. Thank you very much :)